# Progressbar component displayed on multiple lines in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, progress-bar, command-line-interface

I use the [progressbar component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html) in a simple command task with Symfony2 (2.6.6).

My code is like that:

```
...
$progress = new ProgressBar($output, $total);
$progress->start();

if (($handler = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handler, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $this->whatever();
        $progress->advance();
    }
    fclose($handler);
    $progress->finish();
}
...
```

And the output looks like:

```
  0/50 [>---------------------------]   0%
  5/50 [==>-------------------------]  10%
 10/50 [=====>----------------------]  20%
 15/50 [========>-------------------]  30%
 20/50 [===========>----------------]  40%
 25/50 [==============>-------------]  50%
 30/50 [================>-----------]  60%
 35/50 [===================>--------]  70%
 40/50 [======================>-----]  80%
 45/50 [=========================>--]  90%
 50/50 [============================] 100
```

The progress bar is not reloading itself, appears in a new line with each `->advance()`. I'm sure that the function `->whatever();` don't do anything with the output.

Anyone know why this behavior? Thanks you!

*Sorry for my English*

Comment: "If your platform doesn't support ANSI codes, updates to the progress bar are added as new lines." - lines form [SymfonyDoc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html), Is this are you asking for?

Comment: Yes @xurshid29! I did not see this message!! Thankyou!

Comment: @xurshid29: you can add this comment as an answer.

Comment: It's worth also noting I've seen the progress bar break onto new lines if the terminal window is too narrow, even if the platform does support ANSI codes.

Comment: @teaforchris i faced this issue and it took me ages to realise the console window was too narrow until i saw your comment. Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `setOverwrite()` when initializing the progress bar:

```
$progress = new ProgressBar($output, $total);
$progress->setOverwrite(true);

$progress->start();
...
```

This defines whether to overwrite the progressbar, or to create new line line.http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.html#method_setOverwrite

Comment: So what does this do exactly? Need to explain your answer

Comment: This actually is the real answer to this question. I will edit it now to look better

Answer (score 0):

You'd rather use SymfonyStyle (sf >= 2.7) class since Console Helper are now deprecated.

Here is some dummy example:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $console = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
    $console->title('Dummy progressBar example');
    $console->progressStart(100);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
        // do something
        sleep(1);
        $console->progressAdvance();
    }
    $console->progressFinish(); // force progress
    $console->success('Dummy progressBar example complete!');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try $output->setDecorated(true);